# Adding variables into R1C1 formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an Application-defined error for this line of code when I run it. Is the problem that I included a variable inside the R1C1 formula?

```
Dim numPT as In
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=ROUNDDOWN(IF(RC[" & numPT & "]" & "+" & "RC[" & 2 * numPT & "]" & "<=" & "RC15 - SUM(RC17:RC[-1]), RC[" & numPT & "]" & "+" & "RC[" & (2 * numPT) & "],RC15 -SUM(RC17:RC[-1]),0)"
```

Comment: to debug this, you should put a breakpoint just before this line executes, and then check what the string value of your formula evaluates to (using the [immediate window](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/debugging/immediate-window.htm)) . Try taking the formula and manually putting it into a cell to see what complaints Excel has for you

Comment: What is the `ActiveCell`?

Comment: SUM(RC17:RC[-1]) should end in 2 closing brackets (another for the IF(). ie. SUM(RC17:RC[-1]))